# lxml.html search and replace

Tags: python, html, lxml

I need your help or suggestion, whatever.

I start reading some books about python just because of this problem I have :) But I see it will takes long time for me to learn the whole language. I also skimmed and searched through lxml.html documentation but still I can figure out how to do this what I want.

I created two html files for sample, to explain what is my problem. You can see those pieces of code here: http://pzt.me/ltbj

There is also a screenshot with differences so that is even easier to see what's going on.

If somebody tried to do something like this before or if you have an idea how could I do this please let me know.

Thank you.

Best,
Jozsef

OK here is the code:

`~~~~~~~~~~~

This:

~~~~~~~~~~~`

New Document

```
<body>  
    <h2><a name="2" class="class1">2</a></h2> <a href="#top" class="class2">^ top ^</a>  
    <p><span class="class3">20</span>Sed imperdiet, lacus eu consectetur tempus, tellus metus vestibulum tortor, nec tincidunt nisl enim non tortor. <span class="class3">21</span>Nam in aliquam magna. Maecenas hendrerit fringilla dui facilisis aliquet. Phasellus neque justo, aliquet non pellentesque vel, dictum non libero. Phasellus vel nulla mi, id molestie purus. Suspendisse orci ante, imperdiet at tempus id, pulvinar eu mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. <span class="class3">22</span>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque pretium, ligula tristique porta fringilla, mauris lectus gravida nibh, consectetur ornare lacus tellus quis sem. <span class="class3">23</span>Curabitur nibh dui, feugiat sed luctus sed, laoreet sed tortor.</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">24</span>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. <span class="class3">25</span>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">26</span>Sed imperdiet, lacus eu consectetur tempus, "tellus metus vestibulum tortor, nec tincidunt nisl enim non tortor."</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">27</span></p>  
    <p>Nunc volutpat lacus;</p>  
    <p>Etiam sit amet dapibus;</p>  
    <p>Nunc consequat mauris.</p>                 
    <p><span class="class3">15</span>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc volutpat lacus a lacus dignissim sed iaculis metus consectetur. <span class="class3">17</span>Nunc consequat mauris nec ligula ullamcorper ut iaculis nibh sodales. "Nulla tincidunt lorem eu odio laoreet facilisis." <span class="class3">18</span>Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur sagittis, mauris quis laoreet consectetur, erat urna tincidunt augue, ut eleifend felis mi quis felis. <span class="class3">19</span>Vivamus a elit risus, consequat sagittis ligula. Nunc ut vestibulum ipsum. Curabitur at sapien vitae est egestas aliquam. <span class="class3">20</span> Donec porttitor, ligula vel venenatis posuere, purus nunc adipiscing ante, id pellentesque turpis nulla eu magna. <span class="class3">21</span>Praesent gravida, eros ut scelerisque commodo, magna quam volutpat elit, a aliquet neque ligula a mauris. <span class="class3">22</span>Curabitur nibh dui, feugiat sed luctus sed, laoreet sed tortor. <span class="class3">23</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit:</p>   
    <p>Pellentesque pretium, ligula tristique</p>  
    <p>felis viverra;</p>  
    <p>justo lobortis ut "l"</p>  
    <p>unc ut consectetur fermentum.</p>          
    <p><span class="class3">14</span>Proin et tellus felis:</p>  
    <p>Suspendisse potenti,</p>  
    <p>enim non tortor</p>  
    <p>Donec porttitor.</p>  
    <p>Morbi eleifend fermentum</p>  
    <p>Aliquam id ante.</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">15</span></p>  
    <p>Curabitur nibh dui, feugiat sed luctus sed, laoreet sed tortor,</p>  
    <p>etiam ullamcorper.</p>  
    <p>vivamus interdum nulla,</p>  
    <p>odio laoreet facilisis.</p>     
    <p><span class="class3">20</span>Suspendisse potenti. Nam in aliquam magna. Maecenas hendrerit fringilla dui facilisis aliquet. <span class="class3">21</span>Suspendisse potenti. Nam in aliquam magna. Maecenas hendrerit fringilla dui facilisis aliquet. </p>  
</body>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
To become this:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

New Document

```
<body>  
    <h2><a name="2" class="class1">2</a></h2> <a href="#top" class="class2">^ top ^</a>  
    <p><span class="class3">20</span>Sed imperdiet, lacus eu consectetur tempus, tellus metus vestibulum tortor, nec tincidunt nisl enim non tortor. <span class="class3">21</span>Nam in aliquam magna. Maecenas hendrerit fringilla dui facilisis aliquet. Phasellus neque justo, aliquet non pellentesque vel, dictum non libero. Phasellus vel nulla mi, id molestie purus. Suspendisse orci ante, imperdiet at tempus id, pulvinar eu mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. <span class="class3">22</span>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque pretium, ligula tristique porta fringilla, mauris lectus gravida nibh, consectetur ornare lacus tellus quis sem. <span class="class3">23</span>Curabitur nibh dui, feugiat sed luctus sed, laoreet sed tortor.</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">24</span>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. <span class="class3">25</span>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">26</span>Sed imperdiet, lacus eu consectetur tempus, "tellus metus vestibulum tortor, nec tincidunt nisl enim non tortor."</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">27</span><br />  
        Nunc volutpat lacus;<br />  
        Etiam sit amet dapibus;<br />  
        Nunc consequat mauris.</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">15</span>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc volutpat lacus a lacus dignissim sed iaculis metus consectetur. <span class="class3">17</span>Nunc consequat mauris nec ligula ullamcorper ut iaculis nibh sodales. "Nulla tincidunt lorem eu odio laoreet facilisis." <span class="class3">18</span>Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur sagittis, mauris quis laoreet consectetur, erat urna tincidunt augue, ut eleifend felis mi quis felis. <span class="class3">19</span>Vivamus a elit risus, consequat sagittis ligula. Nunc ut vestibulum ipsum. Curabitur at sapien vitae est egestas aliquam. <span class="class3">20</span> Donec porttitor, ligula vel venenatis posuere, purus nunc adipiscing ante, id pellentesque turpis nulla eu magna. <span class="class3">21</span>Praesent gravida, eros ut scelerisque commodo, magna quam volutpat elit, a aliquet neque ligula a mauris. <span class="class3">22</span>Curabitur nibh dui, feugiat sed luctus sed, laoreet sed tortor. <span class="class3">23</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit:<br />  
        Pellentesque pretium, ligula tristique<br />  
        felis viverra;<br />  
        justo lobortis ut "l"<br />  
        unc ut consectetur fermentum.</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">14</span>Proin et tellus felis:<br />  
        Suspendisse potenti,<br />  
        enim non tortor<br />  
        Donec porttitor.<br />  
        Morbi eleifend fermentum<br />  
        Aliquam id ante.</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">15</span><br />  
        Curabitur nibh dui, feugiat sed luctus sed, laoreet sed tortor,<br />  
        etiam ullamcorper.<br />  
        vivamus interdum nulla,<br />  
        odio laoreet facilisis.</p>  
    <p><span class="class3">20</span>Suspendisse potenti. Nam in aliquam magna. Maecenas hendrerit fringilla dui facilisis aliquet. <span class="class3">21</span>Suspendisse potenti. Nam in aliquam magna. Maecenas hendrerit fringilla dui facilisis aliquet. </p>  
</body>
```

Can't include the image. sorry. you must to see the link on top if you want to see the image.
Thanks.

Comment: put the basic code here rather than linking it outside.

Answer (score 2):

**Use BeautifulSoup to parse the document** and recreate it after processing it. It is the easiest thing to do. I wouldn't use lxml for what you are trying to do.

- http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html

Look at example here on how tags are added and removed:

- [Extract all <script> tags in an HTML page and append to the bottom of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980740/extract-all-script-tags-in-an-html-page-and-append-to-the-bottom-of-the-documen)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup

Comment: Ah, BeatifulSoup is an exquisite module. Great suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll go through those pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really that short on time you may be able to accomplish your task after reading chapter 8 of `Dive Into Python` ( http://diveintopython.net/html_processing/index.html ).

Alas, I strongly suggest that you start from the very beginning of the book.

Regular expressions (chapter 7 same book) may also be of great help. I have not quite understood what you're trying to accomplish though. Replace `<p></p>` tags with `<br/>`?

Anyway look into `smgllib` and `re` modules.

Comment: @Soulseekah: Regular expressions may not be a very good idea for html processing. BeautifulSoup can do a good enough job and is much simpler.

Comment: If we're talking search and replace `<p>(.*)</p>` with `groups()+<br/>` there should be no problem. If more parsing power is needed then yes, I agree with you.

Comment: On second thought, yes, it's quite hard, would need to develop quite a solid pattern, since there are `<span>` tags which will be captured with `.*`; Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems. --Jamie Zawinski, in comp.emacs.xemacs

Comment: @Soulseekah: +1 I do agree with you here and a nice quote :)

Comment: It seems beautifulsoap is the way to go. by the way, what I'm trying to do is to replace "<p>text</p>" with "text<br />"  but also in case of <p><span class="classname">10</span>text</p> I need to replace only the closing paragraph tag in that line, but only in case if the next line, below, contains only <p>text</p>. and also, in the last "<p>text</p>" line I need to keep the closing paragraph tag </p>

Comment: seems complicated to me but I know it could be done. because the line after the last "<p>text</p>" (the one which needs to become "text</p>") contains span tag again.