# using BeautifulSoup to insert an element before closing body

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

What is the most efficient way to insert an element as last one in the `body` of an HTML page?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See my answer to a previous question along the same lines:

- [Extract all <script> tags in an HTML page and append to the bottom of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980740/extract-all-script-tags-in-an-html-page-and-append-to-the-bottom-of-the-documen/3980924#3980924)

The following should insert just fine:

```
soup.body.insert(len(soup.body.contents), yourelement)
```

Comment: yes it works but in the meantime, I settled for a simpler solution: `content.replace("""</body>""", """%s</body>""" % NEW)` ... why didn't I think of that before resorting to the big guns?