# BeautifulSoup - Insert text/var into every given td class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML file, and I would have to insert some text / variable into one of the td classes.
The td class, called "foo" sometimes got an ID, sometimes just got a class.

```
<td align="left" class="foo" style="white-space:nowrap;">  </td>
```

Text would go in the empty space. It does not matter if the empty space stays as well, as I use `stripped_strings` later on. That only keeps the string/data anyway.
(This is a generated table, by some enterprise software.)

Found [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980740/extract-all-script-tags-in-an-html-page-and-append-to-the-bottom-of-the-docume/3980924#3980924), but I couldn't figure things out, about how to make it work on td classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<td align="left" class="foo" style="white-space:nowrap;">  </td>')
for td in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'foo'}):
    td.attrs['title'] = 'spam'
    td.append('egg text')
print soup
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize soup:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s) #s is the html string you get
```

First you should find the tag you want:

```
>>> td = soup.find('td', attrs={'class':'foo'})
>>> td
<td align="left" class="foo" style="white-space:nowrap;"> </td>
```

Insert a text:

```
>>> td.string = 'hello'
>>> td
<td align="left" class="foo" style="white-space:nowrap;">hello</td>
```

Add a property:

```
>>> td['id'] = 'id1'
>>> td
<td align="left" class="foo" id="id1" style="white-space:nowrap;">hello</td>
```

Add a class:

```
>>> td['class'].append('foo2')
>>> td
<td align="left" class="foo foo2" id="id1" style="white-space:nowrap;">hello</td>
```

For more, you should read the [doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).